# React search option from API needs running twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

When connecting to the Spotify API through a React app I enter a term to the search box and it loads fine but refreshes the page immediately. Upon searching a second time it works perfectly fine?  Is this an obvious error I am missing?

I have included the code below and appreciate any help

Spotify Fetch

```
const clientId = '//my api key//';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/';

let accessToken;

getAccessToken() {
        if(accessToken) {
            return accessToken;
        }
        const hasAccessToken = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
        const hasExpiresIn = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);
        if (hasAccessToken && hasExpiresIn) {
            accessToken = hasAccessToken[1];
            const expiresIn = Number(hasExpiresIn[1]);
            window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
            window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
            return accessToken;
        } else {
            const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
            window.location = accessUrl;
        }
    },
```

Spotify Search

```
 search(term) {
        const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        }).then(
            response => { 
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    console.log('API request failed');
                }
        }).then(
            jsonResponse => {
            if(!jsonResponse.tracks) {
                return [];
            }
            return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
                    id: track.id,
                    name: track.name,
                    artist: track.artists[0].name,
                    album: track.album.name,
                    uri: track.uri,
                    preview: track.preview_url,
                    art: track.album.images[2].url
            }));
        });
    },
```

Search Component

```
import React from 'react'
import './searchbar.css';

class Searchbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { term: ''}
    this.search = this.search.bind(this)
    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this)
    }

    search() {
        this.props.onSearch(this.state.term)
    }

    handleTermChange(e) {
        this.setState( {term: e.target.value} )
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="SearchBar">
                    <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist" onChange = {this.handleTermChange} />
                    <button className="SearchButton" onClick = {this.search}>SEARCH</button>
                </div>
    }
}

export default Searchbar;
```

Comment: `window.location = accessUrl` will cause a reload of the page

Comment: I need that in there to get client authorisation or the post request later on will not work without it. Any workarounds?

Comment: @DanWilstrop, If I undertand you need for a reload correctly, you need a latest valid token for your next request. Cant we use the concept of `refresh-token` from Spotify API and fetch a valid token?

Comment: I’ve looked at all the documentation and I think the solution is going to be have a log in overlay on page load that grants the access token for use on the main page.